# "Change password system" does not work in user authentication.(Django)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I'm trying to configure Django app with a user authentication model(django-allauth).

It almost works well but when a user tries to change his password, a problem occurs.

Let's say when a user want to change his password, he goes to Password reset page

**Example**

> http://3.129.xx.xxx/accounts/password/reset/

He put his Email address on the form and submit, then he recieve a "Password Reset E-mail" with a link to reset the password.

**Example**

> https://u22207100.ct.sendgrid.net/ls/click?upn=EGpFlOkd4a3JZnFjHjqKqsCiiinSf51vqFvV.....

Cliking above link, the user redirected to

> http://3.129.xx.xxx/accounts/password/reset/key/1-set-password/

But that page has only links "Sign In" and "Sign Up".

It does not have any form to put new password the user want to set.

[Change password page's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbunv.jpg)

In this situation, the user can not change password.
should I set something to allauth system??

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information. Thank you